# Configuring amp-ad with amazon and specific product

Tags: amp-html

[From the amp docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/ads/ads_vendors):

```
      <amp-ad width="300"
        height="250"
        type="a9"
        data-aax_size="300x250"
        data-aax_pubname="identifymyipa-21"
        data-aax_src="302">
      </amp-ad>
```

This displays an ad like so

[image]

How can I display a particular product rather than a generic product? Where are the docs for configuring this

Answer (score 0):

Check the [AMPHTML ad specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/ads/a4a_spec). If all else files, file a request in [Intent to Implement](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4264).